# Now.js module doesn't work (node path not found)

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, node.js

I'm trying to install the Now.js module for Node.js. It gets installed, but it doesn't work. When I install it, here's what I get:

```
eustace@eustace-desktop:/var/www/nowjs$ sudo npm install now -g

> node-proxy@0.5.1 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy
> make

BUILDING: C++ Component
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
'configure' finished successfully (0.038s)
Waf: Entering directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/src/build'
[1/2] cxx: node-proxy.cc -> build/default/node-proxy_1.o
[2/2] cxx_link: build/default/node-proxy_1.o -> build/default/node-proxy.node
Waf: Leaving directory `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/src/build'
'build' finished successfully (0.909s)
now@0.7.4 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/now 
├── node-proxy@0.5.1
└── socket.io@0.8.2
```

I'm trying to get the example working (http://nowjs.com/doc/example), but when I run helloworld_server.js in terminal, here's what I get:

```
eustace@eustace-desktop:/var/www/nowjs$ node helloworld_server.s

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module '/var/www/nowjs/helloworld_server.s'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:421:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
eustace@eustace-desktop:/var/www/nowjs$ node helloworld_server.js

node.js:134
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
        ^
Error: Cannot find module 'now'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:317:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:262:25)
    at require (module.js:346:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/nowjs/helloworld_server.js:7:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:402:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:408:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:334:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:293:12)
    at Array.<anonymous> (module.js:421:10)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)
```

I'm using Node.js v0.4.11 and Ubuntu 11.04. I tried doing 'export NODE_PATH="/usr/local/lib/node"', but it didn't help.
How do I fix this?

Comment: I would Update node.js and go from their.  I have had issues with some of the software that depends on socket.io in node.js 4.0.  If that isn't an option, you might need to download old versions of now.js,socket.io,etc...

Comment: I updated it to v0.5.5, still doesn't work :/

Comment: Oh, and I also get a 'no such environment: Release' error now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I mistyped helloworld_server.js. I wasted around 6 hours trying to fix this, what a stupid mistake :)